# Writing tabs in a specific way (Not from lists) in python

Tags: python, file, tabs

I am new to Python and went through many posts regarding the question I am about to ask. If it is a duplicate, please feel free to put on hold.

Question : To write a file with tabs and multiple values (**not** from a list), i used the following snipet

```
for line in open("dat.Zmine"):
    if "Zavg" in line:
        char  = line.split()[0]
        value = line.split()[1]
        fidzavg.write(str(stepval*filenum))
        fidzavg.write("\t")
        fidzavg.write(value)
        fidzavg.write("\n")
```

where *fidzavg* is the file id . It looks a bit tedious as opposed to say in C++

```
 printf(fidzavg,"%g\t%g\n", stepval*filenum, value)
```

Can i reduce the python snippet to something simular that I put for C++?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do almost exactly the same thing in Python:

```
fidzavg.write("%g\t%g\n" % (stepval*filenum, float(value)))
```

or use `str.format`:

```
fidzavg.write("{0:g}\t{1:g}\n".format(stepval*filenum, float(value)))
```

Note that your assignment from the `line` can be simplified using slicing and tuple (un)packing:

```
char, value  = line.split()[:2]
```